# Netcat as a inetd service on port 1815 and redirect incomming to /dev/ttyS2

Tags: linux, debian, netcat

I'm trying to let my Debian 7 system to listen on port 1815 with `netcat` and redirect the incoming traffic to a VacuumFluorecentDisplay.
Iptables are open and I'm using inetd instead of xinetd(came withe the distro).
But i can't get it to work like i want

added the following line to /etc/services

```
vfd             1815/tcp                      
vfd             1815/udp
```

added the following line to /etc/inetd.conf.

```
vfd stream tcp nowait  root     /bin/nc "-l 1815 > /dev/ttyS2"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong in almost every possible way.

1. Command-line parameters in inetd need to be specified as individual words – not quoted as a single string. For example (only to demonstrate the syntax change; it still won't work as-is):

   ```
   -- vfd stream tcp nowait root /bin/nc "-l 1815 > /dev/ttyS2"
   ++ vfd stream tcp nowait root /bin/nc -l 1815 > /dev/ttyS2
   ```
2. For historical reasons, inetd requires the service's binary *and* the 0th command-line argument to be specified separately, even though they're normally the same. For example (note that 'nc' is now specified twice):

   ```
   -- vfd stream tcp nowait root /bin/nc -l 1815 > /dev/ttyS2
   ++ vfd stream tcp nowait root /bin/nc nc -l 1815 > /dev/ttyS2
   ```
3. inetd does not use a shell to start the services, so there is nothing that would 
   interpret the `> /dev/ttyS2` redirection; everything is simply passed to nc as a command-line argument, and nc doesn't know what to do with it.

   This one requires significant changes – either explicitly using a shell to run your command...

   ```
   -- vfd stream tcp nowait root /bin/nc nc -l 1815 > /dev/ttyS2
   ++ vfd stream tcp nowait root /bin/sh sh -c "nc -l 1815 > /dev/ttyS2"
   ```

   ...or using an entirely different tool, one that is able to open the file without relying on shell redirection:

   ```
   -- vfd stream tcp nowait root /bin/nc nc -l 1815 > /dev/ttyS2
   ++ vfd stream tcp nowait root /bin/socat socat -u tcp-listen:1815 file:/dev/ttyS2
   ```
4. Finally, two programs cannot be told to individually listen on the same port. The whole point of inetd is that *inetd and only inetd* will create the initial "listening" socket, and the inetd-based services will only use the sockets that they've *inherited* from the "parent" inetd. (In 'wait' mode they inherit the "listening" socket, and in "nowait" mode they inherit the individual client-connection sockets.)

   In other words, it doesn't make sense to use `nc -l` as an inetd service, because you're asking it to duplicate everything that inetd has already done. Instead, the service needs to use the existing stdin/stdout (which inetd has attached to the connection socket).

   For example, this should finally work correctly:

   ```
   vfd stream tcp nowait root /bin/sh sh -c "cat > /dev/ttyS2"
   ```

   This should also work:

   ```
   vfd stream tcp nowait root /bin/socat socat -u stdio file:/dev/ttyS2
   ```

Comment: I read your answers and sometimes I think you're the [Nicolas Bourbaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki) of Super User. If you're just one man, all the more kudos to you.